# By mistake manually entered a recurring donation under the wrong account

Tags: drupal, recurring-contributions

By mistake manually entered a recurring donation under the wrong account. Basically I have two users same name. So By confusion add recurring on wrong account. SO Now i want to move it from one account transaction to another account. I know i can disable the recurring on one account and enabled on another account. But i am founding the  way to move recurring transaction one account to another account. Stripe payment processor is working.

Answer (score 2):

Did any monies get processed when you added the recurring Donation? If it did (or did not) will depend on your Payment processor and what pathway you used in CiviCRM to add the Contribution.

If Monies were transacted -> then you'll not just want to Delete the Contribution and re-enter or you'll charge the Credit Card (or Bank Account) again. If you can add some more details to your original question then we can help you find a solution that will work for you.

Comment: I have explained question more check it .

Comment: The answer/best way to handle this greatly depends on the Payment Processor you used - add that to your answer then people can help.

Comment: Payment processor is stripe .

Comment: I don’t work with Stripe but a number of people do - hopefully someone who does will get you the steps needed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CiviCRM.  I think the easiest way to deal with this is to delete the contribution and re-enter it in the correct record, by doing this:

1. Select the record of the contact who has been credited with the
   contribution. In their contribution tab, look over to the far right
   where you will see a "Delete" option against the appropriate
   payment.
2. After taking note of the caption "Deleting this contribution will
   result in the loss of the associated financial transactions if any",
   confirm "Delete".
3. Re-enter the payment in the record of the correct contact.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated the question check it .